# search for element that match the selector in the future

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using {{mustache}} to generate bootstrap modal windows in the "future" and want to call it on click. 
So I use "delegate" to control click on mustache data-toggle="modal" element via parent element which I push with HTML code. Then I want call sibling modalWindow that also was loaded async via template. .delegate() function require me to use 'event' with it, but in my case 'event' is already in place. 
So my question is.. How can I use jQuery to select element in the future without using eventType?

```
 $('#complitedJobsList').delegate('.callModal', 'click', function() {
   $('#complitedJobsList').delegate('#modalID').modal('show');
 }
```

Comment: You only need `$('#modalID').modal('show');`. So long as the element exists when `.callModal` is clicked, it will work fine. Also you shouldn't use `delegate()`, use `on('click', '.callModal', fn);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sounds logical, thanks. Seams there should be other reason why I can't call modal window..